# UDP server packet delay (python)

Tags: python, server, udp

I've created an UDP client-server system. The idea behind it is that multiple clients connect to the server and send it packets. The taks of the server is to send these packets to all the other clients. It's kinda working howerver there is a delay on the clients side where it recieves packets later then it is suspose to arrive. It's almost like the packets are queued and processed later.

Is there anything that can be done against this delay?

I made this for a game which needs multiplayer. The client his worldpostion to the server and the server sends it to the client. If the client recieves the package then apply the movement to the right user. This is where the delay happens!

the way I initialize the server:

```
self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.
self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self.server.bind((self.bind_ip, self.bind_port))
```

The listener 
    request, addr = self.server.recvfrom(1024)

```
if 'position' in decoded_request.
    self.latest_pos['init_connection']["{}:{}".format(addr[0],addr[1])] = 
    decoded_request['position']['coordinates']
    self.broadcast_message(request)
```

Broadcast_message method:

```
def broadcast_message(self, packet):
    for client in self.user_addresses.values():
        self.server.sendto(packet, (client[0], client[1]))
```

The client:

```
data, addr = self.server.recvfrom(1024)
data = json.loads(data.decode)

** here is the code that handles the packet ** a.k.a. apply the movement to the player
```

if it recieves a json with the e.g. a worldposition then apply the movement to the user object that equals the ip.

Comment: Yea, let me take my crystall ball and divinate your code. We can't help you without what you've tried to far

Comment: Sorry! i've updated the post. If I need to provide more info then please let me know!

Comment: How are things threaded?